# Stack Install/Build Packages

Tags: haskell

I have been trying for the past 3 days to learn how can I install packages to use in my haskell program.

I need a package called: 
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-cairo

in order to start using:

**https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart**

I know its probably a silly question, but could someone explain how to install/build an haskel package with **stack** ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do any research first? A google search reveals [extensive `stack` documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).

Comment: [This](http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/04/practical-haskell-getting-started.html) looks like a nice tutorial as well.

Comment: could you please provided more information? which `lts` are you using? have you tried `stack install` already?... you know, just usefull information so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install package using stack simply type `stack install packagename`. Remember to register it in `package.yaml` as dependency in your project, otherwise it won't be visible.

In your case:

`stack install Chart-cairo`

and in `package.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
    - ...
    - Chart-cairo >= 1.9
```